# SOAP API HTTPS - Connecting with Classic ASP

Tags: wcf, soap, asp-classic

I know there are plenty of discussions relating to connecting a classic ASP client to a SOAP web service, but I'm interesting in connecting to a HTTPS enabled SOAP service.

We have an existing SOAP Web service written in WCF and it works great...for .NET clients. We've had a request from a new customer, "We use classic ASP - how do we connect to your Web Service API?" I didn't have a clue where to start, and it started to dawn on me that I had no idea what the structure of the actual SOAP messages are.

I've seen the examples of classic ASP chatting to SOAP web services on the web, but none which exchange messages over HTTPS. We're using message level security on the WCF bindings.

Is this a lost cause - does WS-Security prevent classic ASP from interfacing with a HTTPS SOAP Service?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the https certificate (self signing ? or verified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I came up with the following:

1. WCF Message security can't be used with classic ASP
2. I created a second endpoint on the service which had the following bindings:

   ```
     <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="SecureBasic" >
     <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
       <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
     </security>
     </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>"
   ```

Few notes about this -

1. You'll need to use HTTPS (i.e. install a self-certificate)
2. It's not the preffered method of security to use over the internet - ideally you should use Message security.
3. I used a customer username and password validator to authentciate the client request

The following ASP code works well calling this service:

```
        soapServer = "YourSOAPAddress"
        soapMessage = "Put Your SOAP Message in here use Charlies / Fiddler to determine the message"
        Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") 
        xmlhttp.setOption(2) = 13056
        xmlhttp.open "POST", soapServer, False
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction",   "urn:Alpha.Services.API.DeviceService/IDeviceService/GetDevices"
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        xmlhttp.send(soapMessage)   
        Response.Write "<br>Finished calling Web Service."
        Response.Write "<br>Status = " & xmlhttp.statusText
        Response.Write "<br>ResponseText = " &  xmlhttp.responseText
```

For client systems that use a language that does not support WS-Security (such as ASP) this is one possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: tell your client what year it is, and suggest that there are costs associated with using obsolete technologies, and that one of those costs is that you will not be supporting "Classic ASP".

Option 2: Write some C# code to produce COM wrappers to your services. The Classic ASP code (or VB6 or VBA or whatever) can call COM objects without having any idea they're using modern code developed with modern tools.

Comment: Option 1 is appealing. I take it that other languages such as Java and PHP would be able to support connecting to the SOAP service over HTTPS providing I can determine the structure of the SOAP messages (something I've not yet been able to do, though I'm trying with Fiddler2 and Charles).

Comment: @Simian: you're talking about doing your own implementation of WS-Security?  You're a braver man than I. The question isn't HTTPS, but WS-Security. Java can use it, but I've seen a question recently on SO that suggests that PHP cannot.

Comment: No definitely not. There seems to be numerous messages exchanged when a single SOAP operation called, looking the https traffic. The .net client takes care of all of this, I'm just wondering if there are frameworks for both Java and PHP that will also will negotiate the security of the service.

Comment: @Simian: those messages are part of WS-Security. Java can handle it. Questions here on SO suggest that PHP cannot, though perhaps those questions haven't yet been fully answered. WCF can expose the same service using multiple endpoints. You could expose it using a basicHttpBinding/https endpoint, for customers requiring PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Classic ASP should have no problem working with WS-Security Enabled Web Services. It's just going to be slightly more difficult than you would think. As for the HTTPS part of the equation? That should be transparent to your service. Connecting to something over HTTPS works the same as HTTP.

If all else were to fail, you could resort to manually crafting the SOAP Envelope and putting all of the security details in by hand.

Luckily there's no need for that. Microsoft released the [Microsoft SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en) to make working with Web Services easier. You should be able to handle your situation fairly easily using that.

Comment: -1: "The Microsoft SOAP Toolkit is deprecated by the .NET Framework. SOAP Toolkit support will be retired in April 2005.". It also is not supported on modern OS's, and I don't think it ever supported WS-Security or WS-anything-else!

Comment: @John Saunders - It may be deprecated, but it's deprecated because of the .NET Framework. The OP specifies that he's using classic ASP...SOAP Toolkit is really their only option (deprecated or not). As for WS-Security, the SOAP Toolkit allows you to modify headers to support Basic Username/Password token authentication (as well as also having a hook for X.509 based auth if memory serves).

Comment: @Justin: what about the part about not being supported, and not running on modern operating systems? And it's not their only option - they can create COM wrappers to whatever .NET code they like.

Comment: @John Saunders - If the client doesn't want to move out of the mid-90's, then they're stuck with what was available at the time. Nobody said it would be pretty. I do agree that writing COM wrappers in .NET would be a better option though (if the OP or the Client is willing). That, of course, would assume that the client is willing to install the .NET Framework and isn't using one of those non-modern operating systems. Haha.

Comment: @Justin: .NET Framework is supported on Windows Server 2000. Admittedly, WCF is not, so they may have a problem with accessing the service at all. Alternatively, maybe a less-secure version of the service could be exposed over basicHttpBinding with https.

Comment: @John Saunders - I'm not saying that .NET Framework isn't supported. I'm saying that the client may be un-willing to install it on their servers (considering they're still stuck in the classic ASP days).

Comment: @Justing - thanks for your reply. Is it really feasible to use classic ASP with WS-Security by manually crafting the SOAP envelopes? Looking at the client -> server packets during a single operation call, I can see there is 5 requests made by the client, each of which contains xml nodes such as <t:RequestSecurityToken> <c:DerivedKeyToken> <e:CipherData> <SignatureValue> and lots of encrypted data. Have you ever implemented a solution with success? Thanks for the pointer to the SOAP Toolkit.