# Connect to https SOAP web service in asp classic

Tags: soap, asp-classic

I'm working on a client web site that uses asp classic and wanna to connect this web service `https://acquirer.sb24.com:2789/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL` which uses `https` protocol.
this is my code :

```
SET oSOAPay = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
oSOAPay.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
Call oSOAPay.mssoapinit(WebService, "ReferencePayment")
```

this code works with http web services. any solution to initial http soap web service?

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648207/soap-api-https-connecting-with-classic-asp link can help you.

Comment: Do not use MSSOAP client component; it is 4 or 5 years out of service now.  Not supported.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/946790/48082 for an example of calling a SOAP service with VBScript. It does not matter if it is https or http; the code shown there is the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling WCF service by VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944975/calling-wcf-service-by-vbscript)